# How to retrieve the Date from Excel with Formula by Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, date-formatting

I have an Excel Sheet where the Date Cell is assigned with the Date Formula in Excel `TODAY() + 1`. So basically today it's showing as 03/10/2018 by default. I've created a code to read the data from Excel which has the formula in it but when I'm getting the date it's coming differently.

Code :

```
  Cell c = CellUtil.getCell(r, columnIndex);
  CellType type = c.getCellType();
      if (type == CellType.FORMULA) {
          switch (c.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
                 case NUMERIC:
                      if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(c)) {
                          value = (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(c.getDateCellValue()));
                          data.add(value); // Date should display 03-10-2018 but it's showing 23-01-2018
                      } else {
                          value = (c.getNumericCellValue()) + "";
                          data.add(value);
                      }
                  break;
                  case STRING:
                           value = c.getStringCellValue();
                           data = new LinkedList <String>(Arrays.asList(value.split(";")));
                   break;
              }
      }
```

I don't know why it's showing date from January with the formula applied `TODAY() + 1`

Similar to this another function `TODAY() + 15` returning the 22-04-2018.

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible for me. The code works as expected. But what is `data`? Is it a `List`? And if so what kind of a `List` is it? And where does `data.add(value);` displaying the value?

Comment: For the date, it's not a List but there is some data I'm getting in List for String so I've used List there. In Excel, the cell is date formatted and also has the formula TODAY()+1.

Comment: Again: where does `data.add(value);` displaying the value? Where are you seeing the `23-01-2018`?

Comment: This image might help you... https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DNToSfcCzhNAQcL798etIACr_98DlOQJ

Comment: If that image is true, then the sheet is in a workbook which was evaluated 23-01-2018 last time. So you need [evaluating it first (http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html) before reading. Or you are using a `DataFormatter` together with a `FormulaEvaluator`: `DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();` and then `value = formatter.formatCellValue(c, evaluator);`.

Comment: It worked! It worked!
Thanks, Axel '**The Life Saver**' Richter for the help. At first that throws the Exception `NoClassDefFound org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix` but when I added the dependency for the Common Math 3 it worked very well. I think you can add this as an answer so I can accept it. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [Formula Evaluation](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html):

> "The Excel file format (both .xls and .xlsx) stores a "cached" result
>   for every formula along with the formula itself. This means that when
>   the file is opened, it can be quickly displayed, without needing to
>   spend a long time calculating all of the formula results. It also
>   means that when reading a file through Apache POI, the result is
>   quickly available to you too!"

So all formulas will have cached results stored from the last time they were evaluated. This is either the last time the workbook was opened in Excel, recalculated and saved or from the last time an evaluation was be done outside of Excel.

So if a cell having the formula `=TODAY()` has a cached result of `22-01-2018` stored, then the workbook was evaluated on January 22, 2018 the last time.

To get always current formula results you need [evaluating the formulas first](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html) before reading. Simplest way:

```
...
workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
...
```

Or you are using a [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) together with a [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html):

```
...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); 
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); 
...
Cell cell = CellUtil.getCell(...);
...
String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
...
```