# how POI formula evaluate the same value with the display when float

Tags: apache-poi, formula

I use below code

```
CellValue cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell);
cellValue.getNumberValue();
```

to evaluate formula in xls.   (POI version is 3.9)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqsbq.png)

The display value is 21.1, but parsed value is 21.099999999999998.

Can I get the same value with the display one ?  (I know that POI get the 'cached' value in xml, and excel display the different value based on the xml)

Scale point is not a good solution.

Please give me some advice

Comment: For current versions of `apache poi` the answer would be using a [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) together with a [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html) as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614364/how-to-retrieve-the-date-from-excel-with-formula-by-apache-poi/52658018#52658018. But `apache poi 3.9` might be too old since it is more than 5 years old.

Comment: Great ! It works well. Also I think DataFormatter is so convenient rather than get cell value swtich cell type. Thannnnnks Axel !